# How do I stop HTML table from altering cell height when I dynamically add an image?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to get an image to appear next to a select when an option is chosen. Unfortunately when the image is added in jolts the wholde table. I've tried altering paddings and heights and widths but I'm basically stabbing around in the dark. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out. Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vwWb9/7/

Here is the code. I've put it all into one file so you can easily copy and paste it into your TE to have a look.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">


    @CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

html,body,div,span,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,abbr,address,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,samp,small,strong,sub,sup,var,b,i,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video
    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent
}

body {
    line-height: 1
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section
    {
    display: block
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none
}

blockquote,q {
    quotes: none
}

blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after {
    content: none
}

a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent
}

ins {
    background-color: #ff9;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none
}

mark {
    background-color: #ff9;
    color: #000;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through
}

abbr[title],dfn[title] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    cursor: help
}

table { /*  border-collapse:collapse;*/
    border-spacing: 0
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0
}

input,select {
    vertical-align: middle
}

/**********CUSTOMISED***********/  
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 0.7em
}
/**********END CUSTOMISED***********/
#app_cont {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height: auto;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 200px auto 200px auto;
    background: #efefef;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding: 10px
}

#ab_cont {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0 0px 0;
}

#btn_cont {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #dcdcdc;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.app_btns {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    min-width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    padding: 9px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%, #ededed),
        color-stop(100%, #dfdfdf) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    filter: progid :                                                        
                                          DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
        ( 







                                                   startColorstr = 


                                                     '#ededed', endColorstr = 




                                        '#dfdfdf' );
    background-color: #ededed;
    color: #777777;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.app_btns:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%, #dfdfdf),
        color-stop(100%, #ededed) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100%);
    filter: progid :                                                        
                                          DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
        ( 







                                                   startColorstr = 


                                                     '#dfdfdf', endColorstr = 




                                        '#ededed' );
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.app_btns:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

.disabled {
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 9px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: rgb(156, 156, 156);
    color: #efefef !important;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.disabled:hover {
    cursor: default;
}

#opts_tbl {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:500px;

}

#opts_tbl td {


    padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;

    overflow: hidden;
}

.opt_slcts {
    width: 165px;
    padding: 4px 3px 4px 0px;
    text-indent: 1px;
    line-height: 23px;

}

.val_ers {

    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #1133aa;
}

.val_img {
    float:left;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app_cont">
<div id="opts_pnl">

                <table id="opts_tbl">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="num_slct" class="opt_labels">Options 1:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="num_slct" id="num_slct" class="opt_slcts">
                                <option value="-"   >-</option>
                                <option value="5"   >5</option>
                                <option value="10"  >10</option>
                                <option value="15"  >15</option>
                                <option value="20"  >20</option>
                                <option value="25"  >25</option>
    <!--                        <option value="3"   >3</option>                             -->
                            </select> 
                        </td>
                        <td id="num_slct_er" class="val_ers">Please make a selection.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="tl_c">
                            <label for="top_slct" class="opt_labels">Options 2:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td id="tr_c">
                            <select name="top_slct" id="top_slct" class="opt_slcts">
                                <option value="-"       id="opt-1"                      >-</option>
                                <option value="rnd_sel" id="opt-2"                      >Option</option>
                                <option value="blank"   id="blank" disabled="disabled"  ></option>
                                <optgroup label="Misc.">
                                    <option value="cmn_mis"     id="opt-3">Option</option>
                                    <option value="ib4e"        id="opt-1">Option</option>
                                    <option value="fin_e"       id="opt-1">Option</option>
                                    <option value="dbl_cons"    id="opt-1">Option</option>
                                    <option value="slt_lts"     id="opt-6">Option</option>  
                                    <option value="plrs"        id="opt-1">Option</option>
                                    <option value="blank"       id="blank" disabled="disabled"></option>
                                </optgroup>

                            </select> 
                        </td>
                        <td id="top_slct_er" class="val_ers">Please make a selection.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="bl_c">
                            <label for="diff_slct"  class="opt_labels">Options 3:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td id="br_c">
                            <select name="diff_slct" id="diff_slct" class="opt_slcts">
                                <option value="-" id="item-1">-</option>
                                <option value="1" id="item-2">Option</option>
                                <option value="2" id="item-3">Option</option>
                                <option value="3" id="item-4">Option</option>
                            </select> 
                        </td>
                        <td id="diff_slct_er" class="val_ers">Please make a selection.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div id="btn_cont" unselectable="on">
                        <a href="#" id="strt_btn" class="disabled"  unselectable="on">Start</a>
                        <a href="#" id="help_btn" class="app_btns hlp_btns"  unselectable="on">Help</a>     
                </div>

        </div><!--#opts_pnl-->
    </div><!--#app_cont -->

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$('.opt_slcts').on('change', function(){

        var errors = 0;

        $('.opt_slcts').each(function(){

            var id = this.id + "_er",
                tick = "<img src='images/tick.png' alt='tick' class='val_img'>";

            if($(this).val() == "-"){

                errors++;

                $('#' + id).empty();
                $('#' + id).append('Please make a selection.');

            } else {

                $('#' + id).empty();
                $('#' + id).append(tick);
            }

        });

        if(errors > 0){

            $('#strt_btn').attr('class', 'disabled');

        } else {

            $('#strt_btn').attr('class', 'app_btns');

        }

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: good time to start weaning away from using tables for layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how large these images are supposed, to be, but this seems to fix your issue:

```
.val_ers {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vwWb9/8/

Answer (score 0):

Expand is the natural behavior of display: table-cell; it ignores height/width property.

Try to add `line-height: 24px` to the `td`, it will make the `td`start with the same height as the image.

Comment: line-height won't help you because you dont know the height of the TD.

Answer (score 0):

I see answers like:

```
.val_ers {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but what happens if you create another TD-element with another image?

I would recommend to use:

```
#opts_tbl td {   
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```